# Write subquery in xml.exist()

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sqlxml

I have a table with one column:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
data XML
)GO
```

with one record:

```
INSERT INTO #tmp
VALUES ( N'<RelevanExpertXML><Tel><RelevanExpert>1</RelevanExpert></Tel><Tel><RelevanExpert>2</RelevanExpert></Tel></RelevanExpertXML>')
```

and another tale with one column

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp2
(
id int
)
GO
```

and i want to write this query:

```
select * 
from #temp
where xml.exist('/RelevanExpertXML/Tel/RelevanExpert[(text()) = [select id from     #temp2]]') = 1
```

in fact i want to write sub query in exist(), but i get error, and also i can't change from clause and select list, only i can change where clause.

thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this query:

```
select * 
from #tmp
where exists
    (
       select * 
       from #tmp2 as t
       where
           #tmp.data.exist('/RelevanExpertXML/Tel/RelevanExpert[(text()) = sql:column("t.id")]') = 1
    )
```

but it will return you the whole xml. If you want to split xml by rows, you have to use `nodes()` function in the `from` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
select * 
from #tmp, #temp2
where data.exist('/RelevanExpertXML/Tel/RelevanExpert[text()] = sql:column("id")')=1
```

But I don't think it will give you the results you're after.

You may be after something more like

```
select t.r.value('.','int')
from #tmp temp
cross apply data.nodes('/RelevanExpertXML/Tel/RelevanExpert') t(r)
inner join #temp2 t2 on t.r.value('.','int') = t2.id
```